# the disable functionality is working if I give alert inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to disable the click functionality for the element with id `#sports`. It works if I invoke `alert()` inside the function, but I want it to work without invoking it. If I comment out that code, it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
$("#sports").off("click").on("click", function () {  
  alert("disable click");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disabled it with calling the `off()` method inside the `on()` method:

```js
$("#sports").on("click", function (){   // on button click
  console.log("click disabled");        // Do anything, console.log, alert, anything
  $(this).off("click");            // then disable the click event, set it to off,
                                   // this way the on click event won't fire 
                                   // again unless it's created, again
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sports">Click</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain...so that in future I can fix it myself

Answer (score 0):

What about trying event.preventDefault()?

```
$("#sports").on("click", function (event){  
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   return false;
});
```

But if you want to disable it, you don't have to override its click function - it is enough to set 'disable' property of the DOM element:

```
$("#sports").disabled = true;
```